# LWC Totals Row in Data Table won't push

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, sort, push

I have a LWC with a Lightning data table working and I have a search and a sort function that works as well.

When the data comes from the wrapper class in the apex controller it works fine and there is a working totals row.

I am trying to get the totals row to stay at the bottom on sort and I got the array to remove the totals row with slice and tried to push it back into the array at the end of sort but it won't work.

see my JavaScript function below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import getRoster from '@salesforce/apex/AC_CaptainRosterController.getRoster';
import calculateTotals from '@salesforce/apex/AC_CaptainRosterController.calculateTotals';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Birthdate', fieldName: 'Birthdate', sortable: "true", type: "date"},
    { label: 'Spouse First Name', fieldName: 'AC_Spouse_First_Name', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Souse Last Name', fieldName: 'AC_Spouse_Last_Name', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Address', fieldName: 'MailingAddress', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'City', fieldName: 'MailingCity', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'State', fieldName: 'MailingState', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Spouse Phone', fieldName: 'Spouse_Phone', type: 'phone', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Spouse Email', fieldName: 'Spouse_Email', type: 'email', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Current Classifications', fieldName: 'Current_Classification', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Active Donor', fieldName: 'activeDonor', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'AMB Start Date', fieldName: 'ambStartDate', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'YTD New Contacts', fieldName: 'YTDNewContacts', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'YTD New Ambassadors', fieldName: 'YTDNewAmbassadors', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'YTD Events Hosted', fieldName: 'YTDEventsHosted', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'YTD Activities', fieldName: 'YTDActivitiesTotal', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'YTD Freedom Rewards', fieldName: 'YTDFreedomRewards', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'LCY New Contacts ', fieldName: 'LCYNewContacts', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'LCY New Ambassadors', fieldName: 'LCYNewAmbassadors', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'LCY Events Hosted', fieldName: 'LCYEventsHosted', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'LCY Activities', fieldName: 'LCYActivitiesTotal', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'LCY Freedom Rewards', fieldName: 'LCYFreedomRewards', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Motivation To Be An Ambassador', fieldName: 'AC_Your_Motivation_To_Be_Ambassador'}
];
export default class acCaptainRosters extends LightningElement {
userId = Id;
data;
dataFull;
totalsRow;
error;
totals;
totalsError;
columns = columns;
sortBy;
sortDirection;

@wire(getRoster, {UserId: '$userId'})
rosterData({error, data}){
if(data){
    this.data = data;
    this.dataFull = data;
    this.totalsRow = data.slice(-1);
} else if(error) {
    this.error = error;
    }
}

    doSorting(event) {
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
    }

    sortData(fieldName, direction) {
        const dataTotalRow = this.data.slice(-1);
        const dataWithoutTotal = this.data.slice(0,-1);
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataWithoutTotal));
        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldName];
        };
        // checking reverse direction
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
        // sorting data
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });

        parseData.push(dataTotalRow);
        this.data = parseData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're not using `@track`, and you didn't actually clone the array, so LWC has no idea that you've modified the data. You have two choices.

---

The first is to use track.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
```

...

```
@track data;
```

This tells the platform to watch for changes to the object.

---

Changing the object reference tells LWC that a render cycle needs to occur. The easiest way to do this is with a shallow copy:

```
    this.data = [...parseData];
```

This simple change is enough to let LWC know that it has work to do. You should get the habit of this whenever you're using in-place modifications, such as `Array.prototype.sort` or `Array.prototype.push`, or assigning value to an index.

Comment: I was reading up on LWC recently and I recall it saying in a recent update @Track is no longer necessary, is that true?

Comment: Also the Parse Data line works, it's just the pushing of the totals row that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @MatthewHuston The track change happened two years ago now, not exactly recent. However, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields) says: *Although fields are reactive, the LWC engine tracks field value changes in a shallow fashion. Changes are detected when a new value is assigned to the field by comparing the value identity using ===.* It doesn't track property changes on Arrays and Objects, only total replacements.

Comment: @MatthewHuston Again, if you don't track the variable, expect weird things to happen.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help. I will re-work it with tracking and see what happens!